# Task Scheduler event-based trigger active within certain time frame

Tags: windows-10, windows-task-scheduler

I have successfully set up my task to run on event 4802 (screensaver) but it runs too often as I can be away for a while and ssaver can launch.
Now the trigger definition looks like that

[image]

How to execute the task upon event triggering but **only** within certain time frame, e.g. 10pm - 10am?

`Activate/Expire` setting seems to be active only for specified day, how to enable it to do every day?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the task by this powershell statement, considering our time frame is 8am-8pm:

```
if ([int](get-date -format HH) -gt 8 -or [int](get-date -format HH) -lt 20) {do smth}
```

The statement should be put in Action field of task properties before real action:

[image]

If one want to start something other than Powershell script, one should find an equivalent in PS though.

If somebody knows more elegant/Scheduler-native solution, the answers are welcome.